# Simple todo tutorial memory increased by no activity

Tags: meteor, memory

I have a Meteor app that is based on the Meteor simple todos tutorial. I noticed, that the second node-process (smaller one) on the server, started later when the app is started up, increases its memory usage steadily, even when there is no activity at all but at least one client is logged on to the server. I trace the RSS-Memory value with

```
pmap -x $PID_node | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

but it is also visible with 'top'. The RSS number is increasing steadily when doing nothing at all on the client side. I added the app [here](https://github.com/bpiltz/meteor_simple_todo_tutorial) for reproducing the behavior.

When I remember correctly it is the original state as I finished the tutorial without doing any custom changes.

When the client is disconnected the memory still remains and is not reduced by any means.This goes on until the app is closed on the server when reaching the memory limit. I encounter similar behavior with the official todos-example. I start the apps with

```
meteor --port 61100
```

I found in other posts that this could be related to a public folder which I even do not have in the simple todos so there must be something different. I also updated to the latest version of meteor 1.3.4.1 which does not change the behavior.

Is this a normal meteor behavior or has to be considered a meteor bug? Or is there any bad style code in the examples?